# It is possible to set I2C bus speed programmatically without the bcm2835 library?

Tags: i2c, c, c++

All, I've ported a C++ OLED library from the `bcm2835` library to use `i2c-smbus` to prevent having to run the executable as `root`. (not the best from a security standpoint). However, `i2c-smbus` and `ioctl()` does not provide the ability to set the I2C bus speed (baudrate).

With the `bcm2835` library, you have `bcm2835_i2c_setClockDivider()` which sets the I2C bus clock as a fraction of the system-clock. The specifics of the clock divider are provided by the library's [enum bcm2835I2CClockDivider](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__constants.html#ga98a5303c1b527513fb659472601687bb) (note: that is based on a 250MHz system clock, so there is a multiple of ~4 for the various Raspberry Pi's)

Setting the I2C baudrate in `/boot/config.txt` (e.g. `dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=400000`) isn't an alternative as any program that uses the `bcm2835` to adjust the I2C clock changes the I2C clock system-wide. So it is necessary to set the I2C clock on a per-program basis to ensure a specific bus speed is used.

Is there any other way to set the I2C bus speed programmatically other than the `bcm2835` library? (or version variant of that library) Is there a way do it it without being root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `i2c-smbus` although I have written code in python and c to use I²C using the kernel driver either directly in c or python smbus library.

None of these allow setting clock and rely on the kernel driver.

The bcm2835 library directly accesses the GPIO registers but userspace access to clock functionality is only available using `dev/mem` which requires root permissions (this is the case for all libraries).

Directly accessing the GPIO registers has never been encouraged and no longer is possible on Pi5.

Comment: Well, that helps... but raises the issue, how would this be accomplished on Pi 5? Just in `/boot/config.txt` and then since nothing alters it -- it won't change. But... that brings up the issue of, what to do if you need to change? Not all I2C devices like the same I2C clock... But this is good confirmation that I'm not missing the obvious. I can't find anything but the bcm2835 library that does it -- and I don't like requiring root access to run an executable. I guess you can separate the parts of the program and start as root and then drop privileges after the config is set.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have only had Pi5 for a week so can't offer any alternative. None of the existing libraries will work. I am unaware of any I²C device that doesn't support the standard rates and the BCM2812 is supposed to support 1MHz. It wouldn't be that difficult to write your own kernel driver if you really feel that this is necessary.

Comment: I think that is the way to go. I'll have to go back and make friends with how to associate that driver with the various programs that make use of it. The driver writing itself, I've already found a couple of nice examples that I can draw from. Then it would be a shell wrapper around the C program to `modprobe` or `insmod` the new module before launching the program that relies on it. Thank you again for your suggestions. I'll investigate that route further.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Another possibility. If you have code requiring root access write a module and include a socket server which you run as root. Then a user mode program can access via a socket. This adds some overhead, but is unlikely to impact I²C performance. This is how pigpio works (`pigpiod`)and I have used in my library for hardware PWM (which sets clock). This works on Pi4  and earlier but writing the server on BCM2812 (Pi5) still has many unknowns.

Comment: Yes, the `pigpiod` daemon provides socket access, but it takes 7.6% CPU (minimum when it is idling -- it's polling all 53 GPIOs at 2000 times per second). It spikes to 15-20% of the CPU when you are using it. That's a heck of a penalty just to have a socket backend provided that tries to provide as concurrent as possible notice of a rising or falling edge triggering on any GPIO. Evidently interrupts or polling isn't sufficient from a timing perspective. The non-root, simple approach is to `mmap` the GPIO mem through `/dev/gpiomem` which allows user access - with default perms on the file.

Comment: [Tiny GPIO Access](http://www.abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/tiny_gpio.zip) provides example of this approach - and it is by far the lightest and fastest I've found. Given we have no other takers on this question, I'll go ahead and mark your answer. I've got my hands around what is available and what is a pipe-dream now....

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood my comment. Sockets are a standard and commonly used tool and while they are slow (compared to direct access) they do not have any processing load. The reason pigpio uses resources has nothing to do with the socket but because it has a process which polls every 5microsecond.

Comment: No, no, I got that part, both about sockets and `pigpiod` polling (looping) 2000 times/sec to provide concurrency catching the edge triggers, but thanks for making sure. The varying approaches to providing hardware access from the PiOS just have differing trade-offs. Too bad something similar to the Pico-sdk wasn't provided for PiOS -- but I guess the differing approaches provides one reason why it wasn't. Still not a bad idea and allowing the manner of access to be chosen by `#define` wouldn't be a bad way to go.

Comment: The sockets do not require polling (I use sockets without) although if you require edge triggers possibly. My suggestion about sockets was to use your existing code using bcm2385 but add a socket interface so it could be called from user space without sudo.